# OpenGL glColor3f(r, b, g) while drawing Quads changes colour of whole map

Tags: java, opengl, colors

I'm currently trying to make a game(Java, lwjgl, OpenGL) so that I can get a basic understanding of the how a top down RPG game works(i.e. in learning process). Recently, I tried to implement a healthbar that would hover over the player's sprite, but when I tried to draw it through my Draw class, the display goes haywire and almost everything except the player turn black, while the player sprite itself gets tinted the color passed(in R, G, B) to the Draw method.

The Source Code:

**Player Class**

```
package GameObjects;

import Graphics.ImageLoader;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glPopMatrix;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glPushMatrix;
import org.newdawn.slick.opengl.Texture;
import rpgmain.*;

/**
 *
 * @author Samsung
 */
public class Player extends GameObject{
    private float velX, velY;

    private int curHealth, maxHealth;


    private Texture tex;
    public Player(float x, float y, ObjectId id) {
        super(x, y, id);
        velX = velY = 0;

        curHealth = maxHealth = 100;

        tex = ImageLoader.loadTexture("Player", "png");


    }

    protected void update(ArrayList<GameObject> objects) {
        x += velX;
        y += velY;

        Collisions(objects);

    }

    protected void render() {
        Draw.rect(x, y, 32, 32, tex);
        dispHealth();
    }

    public void Collisions(ArrayList<GameObject> objects) {
        for(GameObject obj : objects) {
            if(obj.getId() == ObjectId.WaterTile) {
                if(Collision.checkCollision(getBoundsTop(), obj.getBounds())) {
                    velX = velY = 0;
                    y = obj.getY() - 32;
                }
                if(Collision.checkCollision(getBoundsBottom(), obj.getBounds())) {
                    velX = velY = 0;
                    y = obj.getY() + 32;
                }
                if(Collision.checkCollision(getBoundsLeft(), obj.getBounds())) {
                    velX = velY = 0;
                    x = obj.getX() + 32;
                }
                if(Collision.checkCollision(getBoundsRight(), obj.getBounds())) {
                    velX = velY = 0;
                    x = obj.getX() - 32;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void dispHealth() {
        Draw.rect(x, y + 34, 10, 5, 1F, 0F, 0F); //THIS CODE TINTS THE PLAYER RED
    }

    public void setVelX(float velX) {
        this.velX = velX;
    }

    public void setVelY(float velY) {
        this.velY = velY;
    }


    public Rectangle getBounds() {
        return new Rectangle((int)x, (int) y, 32, 32);
    }
    public Rectangle getBoundsTop() {
        return new Rectangle((int)x + 7, (int) y + 26, 16, 6);
    }
    public Rectangle getBoundsBottom() {
        return new Rectangle((int)x + 7, (int) y, 16, 6);
    }
    public Rectangle getBoundsLeft() {
        return new Rectangle((int)x + 4, (int) y, 1, 32);
    }
    public Rectangle getBoundsRight() {
        return new Rectangle((int)x + 31, (int) y, 1, 32);
    }
    public Rectangle getBoundsCentre() {
        return new Rectangle((int)x + 20, (int) y, 4, 32);
    }

}
```

**Draw Class**

```
package rpgmain;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import org.newdawn.slick.opengl.*;
/**
 *
 * @author Samsung
 */
public class Draw {

    public static void rect(float x, float y, float width, float height, Texture tex) {
        glTranslatef(x, y, 0);
        //glColor3f(1F, 1F, 1F);
        glClearColor(0.7f, 0.7f, 0.7f, 1.0f);
        tex.bind();
        glBegin(GL_QUADS); //Specifies to the program where the drawing code begins. just to keep stuff neat. GL_QUADS specifies the type of shape you're going to be drawing.
        {
            //PNG format for images
            glTexCoord2f(0,1); glVertex2f(0, 0);  //Specify the vertices. 0, 0 is on BOTTOM LEFT CORNER OF SCREEN.
            glTexCoord2f(0,0); glVertex2f(0, height); //2f specifies the number of args we're taking(2) and the type (float)
            glTexCoord2f(1,0); glVertex2f(width, height); 
            glTexCoord2f(1,1); glVertex2f(width, 0);
        }


        glEnd();
    }

    public static void rect(float x, float y, float width, float height, Texture tex, float r, float g, float b) {
        glTranslatef(x, y, 0);
        glColor3f(r, g, b);

        tex.bind();
        glBegin(GL_QUADS); //Specifies to the program where the drawing code begins. just to keep stuff neat. GL_QUADS specifies the type of shape you're going to be drawing.
        {
            glTexCoord2f(0,0); glVertex2f(0, 0);  //Specify the vertices. 0, 0 is on BOTTOM LEFT CORNER OF SCREEN.
            glTexCoord2f(0,1); glVertex2f(0, height); //2f specifies the number of args we're taking(2) and the type (float)
            glTexCoord2f(1,1); glVertex2f(width, height);
            glTexCoord2f(1,0); glVertex2f(width, 0); 
        }
        glEnd();
    }
    public static void rect(float x, float y, float width, float height, float r, float g, float b) {
        glTranslatef(x, y, 0);
        glColor3f(r, g, b); //Problem seems to be here

        glBegin(GL_QUADS); //Specifies to the program where the drawing code begins. just to keep stuff neat. GL_QUADS specifies the type of shape you're going to be drawing.
        {     
            glVertex2f(0, 0);  //Specify the vertices. 0, 0 is on BOTTOM LEFT CORNER OF SCREEN.
            glVertex2f(0, height); //2f specifies the number of args we're taking(2) and the type (float)
            glVertex2f(width, height);
            glVertex2f(width, 0); 
        }
        glEnd();
    }

}
```

I don't know whether to include other classes as well,but I guess I'll include the GameObject class as well.

**GameObject Class**

```
package rpgmain;

import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 *
 * @author Samsung
 */
public abstract class GameObject {
    protected float x, y;
    ObjectId id;

    public GameObject(float x, float y, ObjectId id) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.id = id;
    }
    protected abstract void update(ArrayList<GameObject> objects);
    protected abstract void render();
    public abstract Rectangle getBounds();

    public float getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(float x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public float getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(float y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public ObjectId getId() {
        return id;
    }

}
```

Comment: Try to unbind your textures after you are done with drawing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. There where two main problems with my code, ll in the Draw class.

1. GL_TEXTURE_2D
   I disabled this using glDisable(GL_Texture_2D) every time I started drawing a a normal non textured rectangle, and enabled it after I was done, and did the reverse in the texture drawing method (i.e. enable before start drawing, disable after finish). This resulted in the health bar actually showing up.
2. glColor3f(r, g, b);
   This is the actual problem of the question. The rectangle ended up tinting every texture on the display because I did not know that glColor3f affects every Vertex you draw. So to tackle this, before drawing a textured QUAD, I set it's color to white first(using glColor4f(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f);) and everything rendered perfectly.

The changes:

```
 public static void rect(float x, float y, float width, float height, Texture tex) {
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glTranslatef(x, y, 0);        
        glColor4f(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f); //NEEDS to be white before drawing, else stuff will tint.
        tex.bind();
        glBegin(GL_QUADS); //Specifies to the program where the drawing code begins. just to keep stuff neat. GL_QUADS specifies the type of shape you're going to be drawing.
        {
            //PNG format for images
            glTexCoord2f(0,1); glVertex2f(0, 0);  //Specify the vertices. 0, 0 is on BOTTOM LEFT CORNER OF SCREEN.
            glTexCoord2f(0,0); glVertex2f(0, height); //2f specifies the number of args we're taking(2) and the type (float)
            glTexCoord2f(1,0); glVertex2f(width, height); 
            glTexCoord2f(1,1); glVertex2f(width, 0);
        }
        glEnd();
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    }
```